# Compiling Spark Scala Program into jar file using installed spark and maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

Still trying to get familiar with maven and compiling my source code into jar files for spark-submit. I know how to use IntelliJ for this but would like to understand how this actually works. I have an EC2 server with all of the latest software such as spark and scala already installed and have the example SparkPi.scala source code I would like to now compile with maven. My silly questions are firstly, can I just use my installed software for building the code rather than retrieving dependencies from maven repository and how do I start off with a basic pom.xml template for adding the appropriate requirements. I don't fully understand what maven is exactly doing and how can I just test a compilation for my source code?
As I understand it, I just need to have the standard directory structure `src/main/scala` and then want to run `mvn package`. Also I would like to test with maven rather than sbt.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Run example on the local machine or run example on a cluster.

Comment: Trying to run example on spark cluster on EC2. I know how to compile locally with IntelliJ but what is the correct method for compiling source code on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition to @Krishna, 
If you have `mvn project`, use  `mvn clean package` on `pom.xml`. Make sure you have the following `build` in your `pom.xml` to make `fat-jar`. (This is my case, how I'm making jar)

```
<build><sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins><plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin></plugins>
    </build>
```

For more detail: [link](https://github.com/hastimal/StormTwitterApp/blob/master/pom.xml)
If you have `sbt project`, use `sbt clean assembly`to make `fat-jar`. For that you need the following config, as an example in `build.sbt`

```
assemblyJarName := "WordCountSimple.jar"
//
val meta = """META.INF(.)*""".r

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
  case n if n.startsWith("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case n if n.endsWith(".conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case meta(_) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Also `plugin.sbt` like:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

For more see [this](https://github.com/hastimal/SparkTutorials/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt) and [this](https://github.com/hastimal/SparkTutorials/blob/master/build.sbt).

Till here main goal is to get fat-jar with all dependencies in target folder. Use that jar to run in cluster like this:

```
hastimal@nm:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/spark-submit --class  com.hastimal.wordcount --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 15 --executor-memory 52g --executor-cores 7 --driver-memory 52g  --driver-cores 7 --conf spark.default.parallelism=105 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g --conf spark.network.timeout=300  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4608 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4608 --conf spark.akka.frameSize=1200  --conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4 --conf spark.rdd.compress=true --conf spark.broadcast.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.manager=sort /users/hastimal/wordcount.jar inputRDF/data_all.txt /output
```

Here I have `inputRDF/data_all.txt /output` are two args. Also in tool point of view I'm building in `Intellij`as IDE.

Comment: Thank you. So basically as I understand it. You don't need to include the spark or scala dependencies in your pom.xml? Want to understand why I sometimes see all software dependencies in the pom.xml versus leaving it out as you have shown. And when you code in IntelliJ, are you simply adding spark and scala as modules and then just running the basic maven build to creating fat-jar for spark-submit?

Comment: @prometheus2305 In short answers to your question: 1. Yes, we need all dependencies , required for App, in `build.sbt` or `pom.xml`. 2. I'm making Scala-SBT project and then adding stuff in `build.sbt` and in `plugin.sbt`. That's the easiest way to for my knowledge. Use links that I referred above.

Comment: still a little confused. If I only need to package the project into jar for running it on spark-submit on a separate remote cluster that already has spark do I need to explicitly add spark and scala in pom.xml to include those dependencies in the jar or do I just need a minimal maven only for compile and creating a jar file?

Comment: Yup, copy `pom.xml` if you have already from any project else if you're making new project then make from scratch and add dependencies in `pom.xml` and later if you have code existing then put that code in `src`. If you don't have the code then write for the new project. My point is to make `fat-jar` you need to add these `build`. Make sense? Let me know if have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below

```
# create assembly jar upon code change
sbt assembly

# transfer the jar to a cluster 
scp target/scala-2.10/myproject-version-assembly.jar <some location in your cluster>

# fire spark-submit on your cluster
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class not.memorable.package.applicaiton.class --master yarn --num-executor 10 \
  --conf some.crazy.config=xyz --executor-memory=lotsG \
  myproject-version-assembly.jar \
  <glorious-application-arguments...>
```