# How to export all the dependency jar in one dependency jar in Intellij IDEA ide?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am writting a Spark-shell script and for some reason I have been told to not provide the code in a jar form rather than just a plain spark scala shell script.

My application would focuses on reading kafka streams to spark. But since Kafka stream is not part of the spark, I would need to supply the kafka stream dependency jar while submitting to spark-submit.

I have written the Spark script in IntellijIDEA IDE. I am also having some other dependencies which are visible under the "external Libraries" section of the IDE.

Now how can I create a single dependency jar out of the "external libraries" so that I can supply it while submitting my spark script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling Spark Scala Program into jar file using installed spark and maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930875/compiling-spark-scala-program-into-jar-file-using-installed-spark-and-maven)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Comment: @philantrovert My question is not a duplicate of the links which you have suggested. I am NOT asking "how to create a package jar of my application?" rather, I am asking "how to create a common dependency jar which does not include my Spark Script?" so that I can submit my script to Spark using command "spark-submit <my spark scala script> --jar <my common depedency jar file>". If you find any duplicates for this question please let me know. I would be thankful.